# connect to linux machine from windows via java Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, linux, windows

Hi I want to connect to linux machine from windows via java. I was searching via internet and fide code like:

```
public  void testExec() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh myhost");

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    out.println("ls -l /home/me");
    while (in.ready()) {
      String s = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(s);
    }
    out.println("exit");

    p.waitFor();
}
```

But i can't understand how set my login and passsword. Does anybody trying such way to connect to linux, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

This would be far too complicated !

You should import and use [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which runs like a charm in java  (eclipse ant and many other tools use it)